# pass special character in linux shell script argument

Tags: linux, shell

I would like to pass the password argument in the argument when calling a shell script but it doesnt work

This is the code I have:

```
./abc.sh abc.ftp.com user1234 password?233@jio&abc
```

At password stage it got stuck.
any idea?

Comment: `./abc.sh abc.ftp.com user1234 'password?233@jio&abc'`

Comment: i tried. doesnt work . not sure why

Comment: What exactly means "doesn't work"? Maybe you missing quotes in your script. (Probably you will need double quotes.) Please [edit] your question, copy&paste the code of your script and format it as a code block using the `{}` tool of the editor field..

Comment: I just saw a mistake in my comment but can no longer edit it. The second sentence should be: Maybe you also have missing quotes in your script.